# How to check whether the username and password exist in the sql server (Kotlin)

Tags: sql-server, kotlin

How do I check whether the username and password exist in the sql server (Kotlin)? I would like to know if it is possible to recognize whether the user has entered the wrong username or password instead of just saying they have entered the wrong credential.

Comment: How did you store password? Is it encrypted or just string?

Comment: Currently I trying for string since I would like to know how it works before moving on to encrypted

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this at all†, make it simple -

```sql
select Password
from dbo.Users
where UserName = 'whatever';
```

If the query returns no results, you know that it wasn't a valid username. Conversely, if it did you know that you have a valid username and it's up to the client to check whether the password is valid.

† A reason you may not want to do this is that it's generally not a great practice to tell an attacker that they, in fact, have a valid username but have only failed on the password.